Female fight scene from a movie or TV show, 1979 or 1980
This is probably a tough one but it never hurts to ask.  One night in High School (10th-11th grade), lateish, probably shortly after midnight, maybe 11:30 PM.   I turned on the TV for a few minutes, regular TV not cable and I happened to see this all girl fight scene that made an impression and I never forgot.
It was in a barracks or something, so I assume they were army/or something like that, 5 or 6 women and they were sparing, in a friendly way, 4 or 5 against 1.  I guess the 1 of them was a really good fighter, and I'm sure by today's standards it would be cheezy and fake, but at the time I loved it.
The only think I remember, one of the 4 or 5 ladies, the smallest one, they kept showing her crouching in the distance, waiting to jump in, and when she finally tried to jump the 1 lady from behind, that lady gave her a side-kick to the stomach that sent her flying backwards and knocked her half way through the wall, and she spent the rest of the fight holding her belly with a not happy look on her face.
A moment or two later, the boss walked in and said something like "enough fun, we have a mission" or something to that effect and the line I remember was the lady who was half way through the wall still holding her stomach said "yeah, fun".
Not much to go on unless somebody saw it too and remembers what it was.   I'd recognize it if I saw it.

The only woman I can really remember that might star in a movie like that was the "Female Chuck Norris"; Cynthia Rothrock, although her movie career didn't begin until the mid 80's.

No, I'm quite certain of the dates, had to be 1980 or before.  (just maybe 1981, but no later).    it was on late night TV so it could have been a re-run or a movie made years before, but not after.   It also wasn't a single female lead but it was more of a team of 5 ladies kind of thing.

Both Wonder Woman and Charlie's Angels were airing at that time. If it were one of those, it sounds like the plot would have be related to the hero going undercover inside some kind of organization of women who are good at combat. The last two episodes of Wonder Woman (which aired in 1979) have her going undercover, but it doesn't seem like there are many women in the cast for those episodes - maybe they were uncredited?

Could it have been in a prison instead of a barracks? Charlie's Angels has at least two episodes, including one from 1979, where a single angel goes undercover in a prison as an inmate.

Definitely not Charlie's angels.  Besides, these 5 or 6 women were friends with each other.   I don't think you'd get a friendly but little rough sparing match in a prison and that's basically what this was.  It wasn't a real fight.   I know both those shows well.   Neither was really late nite TV material and I'd have recognized them.

This sounds like Naked Weapon, which is a 2002 Hong Kong action-thriller. It stars Maggie Q, Anya Wu & Daniel Wu. 
Women are kidnapped when they are young & forced to fight each other. They are kept & fight in a barracks type setting. The survivors of these fights are forced to become assassins. 
I know this film is newer, but it has the feel of an older film.


Provide links 2)The title says the movie is from '79-80: are you sure this is the correct answer?


No, I'm not sure. I am new here, so couldn't put it as a comment.

It was definitely 79-80 range (or before) cause I was in high school when I saw it on TV and I graduated class of 1981.   It was also American.  Mostly white women.   Not foreign.   It made a big impression on me at the time.

Flagging as not answer as answer mentions in comment , he cannot put as comment so he added as answer.

@Panther It's an answer, the answerer only conceded that they aren't certain that it is the correct answer, which is fine.
